# Arrow function from meteor build is crashing heroku deploy

Tags: javascript, heroku, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have deployed a js application on heroku that uses meteor. The build works on localhost but fails on the heroku server. I checked the logs and found this:

```
.js:312:12)
2017-03-18T03:29:07.070711+00:00 app[web.1]: const unicodeNormalizePath     = (path) => {
2017-03-18T03:29:07.074825+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2017-03-18T03:29:07.074821+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
2017-03-18T03:29:07.074824+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2017-03-18T03:29:07.070741+00:00 app[web.1]:                                          ^
```

This gave me the thought that it was not compatible with ES6 arrow functions so I installed ecmascript for meteor to make it compatible with ES5.

This has not solved the problem and this arrow function is still crashing the web app.

Any suggestions on how to stop this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem using, probably, an old buildpack for Heroku. I switched to the buildpack https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse.git and it solved the problem perfectly.

Working buildpack:

```
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse.git
```

I also disabled the previous buildpack by typing:

```
heroku config:unset LINK_TO_OLD_BUILDPACK_REPO
```

The old one I used was https://github.com/jordansissel/heroku-buildpack-meteor.git

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use babel to transform es6 to es5

Comment: Hi, I have been using an ES6 Translator but it isn't working on the meteor build...

Comment: Meteor 1.4 already does that, the problem is probably the node version being used in Heroku that a build pack solves.

Comment: Thanks @Mário! This helped me as well! Your answer should be marked .