# Application Error Heroku deploying with meteor JS

Tags: meteor, heroku

Hi my meteor js app  is showing the following:

Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

---

Here is the commands I ran (by following a tutorial, to get deployed thus far):

heroku create mkrteach 
heroku addons:create mongolab 
heroku config:set ROOT_URL=https://mkrteach.herokuapp.com/ 
git push heroku master

---

Here is what my heroku logs are showing:

```
2017-05-24T23:43:20.191506+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user 

mohammadhunan@gmail.com
2017-05-24T23:43:20.191506+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user mohammadhunan@gmail.com
2017-05-24T23:43:20.019249+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user mohammadhunan@gmail.com
2017-05-24T23:43:20.019249+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user mohammadhunan@gmail.com
2017-05-24T23:43:43.106898+00:00 app[api]: Attach MONGODB (@ref:mongolab-round-29311) by user mohammadhunan@gmail.com
2017-05-24T23:43:43.106898+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user mohammadhunan@gmail.com
2017-05-24T23:44:21.663825+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user mohammadhunan@gmail.com
2017-05-24T23:44:21.663825+00:00 app[api]: Set ROOT_URL config vars by user mohammadhunan@gmail.com
2017-05-24T23:44:32.978581+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user mohammadhunan@gmail.com
2017-05-24T23:44:32.978581+00:00 app[api]: Set METEOR_SETTINGS config vars by user mohammadhunan@gmail.com
2017-05-24T23:44:50.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user mohammadhunan@gmail.com
2017-05-24T23:46:56.713557+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 9e5efce2 by user mohammadhunan@gmail.com
2017-05-24T23:46:56.713557+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user mohammadhunan@gmail.com
2017-05-24T23:46:56.746656+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user mohammadhunan@gmail.com
2017-05-24T23:44:50.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-05-24T23:47:04.554518+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `.meteor/heroku_build/bin/node .meteor/heroku_build/app/main.js`
2017-05-24T23:47:07.867019+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2017-05-24T23:47:07.886082+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-05-24T23:47:07.887443+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-05-24T23:47:07.715326+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-24T23:47:07.715736+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/mini-files.js:82
2017-05-24T23:47:07.716081+00:00 app[web.1]: const unicodeNormalizePath = (path) => {
2017-05-24T23:47:07.716147+00:00 app[web.1]:                                      ^
2017-05-24T23:47:07.741911+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
2017-05-24T23:47:07.741913+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
2017-05-24T23:47:07.741914+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2017-05-24T23:47:07.741915+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2017-05-24T23:47:07.741915+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2017-05-24T23:47:07.741916+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2017-05-24T23:47:07.741917+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2017-05-24T23:47:07.741918+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:9:13)
2017-05-24T23:47:07.741918+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2017-05-24T23:47:07.741919+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2017-05-24T23:47:07.741919+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2017-05-24T23:47:12.921976+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `.meteor/heroku_build/bin/node .meteor/heroku_build/app/main.js`
2017-05-24T23:47:14.666363+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/mini-files.js:82
2017-05-24T23:47:14.665865+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-24T23:47:14.672056+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
2017-05-24T23:47:14.666824+00:00 app[web.1]:                                      ^
2017-05-24T23:47:14.672057+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2017-05-24T23:47:14.666765+00:00 app[web.1]: const unicodeNormalizePath = (path) => {
2017-05-24T23:47:14.672054+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
2017-05-24T23:47:14.672058+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2017-05-24T23:47:14.672058+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2017-05-24T23:47:14.672059+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2017-05-24T23:47:14.672059+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2017-05-24T23:47:14.672060+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:9:13)
2017-05-24T23:47:14.672062+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2017-05-24T23:47:14.672061+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2017-05-24T23:47:14.672061+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2017-05-24T23:47:14.751083+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-05-24T23:47:14.731102+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2017-05-24T23:47:27.649678+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mkred-teach.herokuapp.com request_id=ee6e0ca4-3bee-48ae-925a-562d23e47dd7 fwd="208.185.23.206" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-24T23:47:28.143232+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mkred-teach.herokuapp.com request_id=5c736339-3336-4c8a-986a-ae572f99a441 fwd="208.185.23.206" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
Mohammads-MacBook-Pro:mkrED2 minimoe$
```

I'm not sure how to fix this, can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: which meteor buildpack to use ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrow function from meteor build is crashing heroku deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42870295/arrow-function-from-meteor-build-is-crashing-heroku-deploy)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. It seems the Heroku buildpack you are using no longer works. Change the buildpack to a newer one. This one is working: https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse.git.

To change your buildpack you can use the dashboard or the command-line.

**Via Dashboard**

1. Go to your Heroku dashboard and select your app
2. Go to the Settings tab and find Buildpacks section
3. Remove the existing buildpack and add the new one

**Via command-line**

Find out which buildpack you are using, with

```
heroku buildpacks
```

Copy the link to the old buildpack's git repo.

```
heroku config:unset REPLACE_WITH_OLD_BUILDPACK_LINK

heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse.git
```

Whatever method you use, you'll have to push an update with `git push heroku master` to rebuild the app.